# Alternate Sum of Cubes Using Identity

Tags: summation

> By using $x^3-(x-y)^3 = y(3x^2-3xy+y^2)$, find the value of
>   $$(1^3-2^3+3^3-\cdots+9^3)\times3 + (10^3-11^3+12^3-\cdots-19^3).$$

I find different solutions regarding the alternate sum of cubes here, but none of the solutions shows a clear usage of the identity. I was thinking about grouping $10^3$ and $11^3$ first, but that would give me $x=10$ and $y=-1$ and it does not seem to be useful. I would appreciate any help.

- I am looking for solutions **without** using the sum of cubes identity. Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You have a formula for the sum of cubes, which I suppose you know. For the alternate sum of cubes, let me take the first alternate sum as an example:
\begin{align}
1^3-2^3+3^3-\cdots+9^3&=(1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+9^3)-2(2^3+4^3+6^3+8^3)\\
&=(1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+9^3)-2\cdot 2^3(1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3)
\end{align}
Can you continue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand this method, but I am curious about the solution using the given identity. In other words, one should be able to do it without the sum of cubes formula.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I had overlooked the question. I'll think about this other method.